# Azure Service Charge For A Worker Role

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-worker-roles

I'm just wondering what would happen if I have a worker roles hosting in Azure, and instead of

```
public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
    {
        public override void Run()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                Trace.TraceInformation("Working", "Information");
            }
        }

     //Other code remove for brevity
    }
}
```

I do

```
public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
        {
            public override void Run()
            {
                while (true)
                {                       
                }
            }

         //Other code remove for brevity
        }
    }
```

I know that the second code snippet spinning the process all the time, which is bad. But is there any other differences in terms of money?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't produce network transfer, that second `while(true)` code would simply block your worker role's main thread if each iteration takes few milliseconds to be processed.

You can check how worker roles are billed using [Azure Pricing Calculator for cloud services](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=cloud) (and you'll discover that you pay a fixed price per month based on CPU power and RAM, and also based on network bandwidth).